# The history of 'aisle' and 'isle'

Tags: etymology, history, french

I've read about how the word 'aisle' and 'isle' each came from the French 'aile' and 'ile', respectively. I also read how the there was confusion between the two words, such that when 'isle' gained its 's', 'aisle' soon followed. Does anyone know the full story?

Comment: They put it in because they thought it was historical, so put in the one from Latin *insula*. But an *island* never needed it any more than an *ait* or *eyot* did, for the original versions never had it.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the discussion of *island* and *isle* in John Ayto, *Arcade Dictionary of Word Origins* (1990):

> **island** [OE] Despite their similarity, *island* has no etymological connection with *isle* (their resemblance is due to a 16th-century change in the spelling of *island* under the influence of its semantic neighbour *isle*). Island comes ultimately from a prehistoric Germanic *aujō, which denoted 'land associated with water,' and was distantly related to Latin *aqua* 'water'. This passed into Old English as *īeg* 'island,' which was subsequently compounded with *land* to form *īegland* 'island'. By the late Middle English period this had developed to *iland*, the form which was turned into *island*. (A diminutive form of Old English *īeg*, incidentally, has given us *eyot* 'small island in a river' [OE].)
>
> *Isle* [13] itself comes via Old French *ile* from Latin *insula* (the *s* is a 15th-century reintroduction from Latin). Other contributions made by *insula* to English include *insular* [17], *insulate* [16], *insulin*, *isolate* [via Italian) [18], and *peninsula* [16].

Meanwhile, Ayto offers this comment on *aisle*:

> **aisle** [15] The original English form of this word was *ele*. It was borrowed from Old French, which in turn took it from Latin *āla* 'wing' (the modern French form of the word aile, has a diminutive form *aileron* 'movable control surface on an aircraft's wing' [20], which has been acquired by English). Besides meaning literally 'bird's wing,' *āla* was used metaphorically for 'wing of a building,' which was the source of its original meaning in English, the 'sides of the nave of a church.' The Latin word comes from an unrecorded *acsla, which is one of a complex web of 'turning' words that include Latin *axis*, Greek *axon* 'axis,' Latin *axilla* 'armpit' (whence English *axillary* and *axil*, and English *axle*.
>
> The notion of an aisle as a detached, separate part of a building led to an association with *isle* and *island* which eventually affected Middle English *ele*'s spelling. From the 16th to the 18th century the word was usually spelled *ile* or *isle*. A further complication entered the picture in the 18th century in the form of French *aile*, which took the spelling on to today's settled form *aisle*.

Glynnis Chantrell, *The Oxford Dictionary of Word Histories* (2002), and Eric Partridge, *Origins: A Short Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1966), offer similar accounts of the relevant words, but Ayto's discussion is the most detailed and most readable of the three.